# Как сделать серию запросов через CURL

Tags: php, curl, авторизация

Для получения файла xml в Битрикс нужно сделать по очереди 3 запроса:

```
site.ru/1c_exchange.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth
```

---

```
site.ru/my_exchange_1.php?type=sale&mode=init&sessid=97a6199349284dc04a8047d05b4dfadc&version=2.08
```

---

```
site.ru/my_exchange_1.php?type=sale&mode=query&sessid=97a6199349284dc04a8047d05b4dfadc
```

---

Где `sessid` изменяется, сделал код который получает `sessid`, пробую сделать второй запрос и не получаю ответ.

Код:

```
    $url = "http://site.ru/my_exchange_2.php?type=sale&mode=checkauth ";  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process  
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;

    $pos  = strripos($result, "sessid");
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $str = strpos($result, "sessid"); 
        $sessid = substr($result, $str);

        echo $sessid."<br>";
    }

    $url = "http://site.ru/my_exchange_2.php?type=sale&mode=query&".$sessid."";  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А вы уверены, что у вас не включена защита передачи идентификатора сессии через адресную строку?

**session.use_only_cookies on**

Comment: Отключил session.use_only_cookies on, сейчас параметр в состоянии off. Но проблема не решилась, второй запрос выдает пустой экран.

Answer (score 0):

Может проблема в этом:

```
$url = "http://site.ru/my_exchange_2.php?type=sale&mode=query&".$sessid."";
```

Заменить на:

```
$url = "http://site.ru/my_exchange_2.php?type=sale&mode=query&sessid=".$sessid;
```

Comment: Не влияет, спасибо! Похоже проблема на стороне Битрикса.